# Jquery validating - comparing the content of jquery variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a script which allows users to up load image files. Each user has an account to login and when they do so a data table is read and returns a list of screens associated to their account.

The user selects a screen and a jQuery script returns the screen resolution.

```
var w;
var h;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#board').change(function(){
    $.get('check_override_image.php', { RecordID: form2.board.value },
    function(result) {
        result = JSON.parse(result);
        w = result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayWidth"];
        h = result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayHeight"];
        $('#size').html("Display width: " + result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayWidth"] 
                + ",<br> Display height: " + result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayHeight"]).show();

        if (result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayType"] == 'P' ) {
            $("#portrait").show();
            $("#landscape").hide();
            $("#SelectView").show();
            $("#SelectViewText").show();
        } else {
            $("#landscape").show();
            $("#portrait").hide();
            $("#SelectView").show();
            $("#SelectViewText").show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The user clicks on a "Browse" link to select an image from their local drive and another jQuery script returns the image filename and the image dimensions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//LOCAL IMAGE
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#image_field").change(function (e) {
        var file, img;
        if ((file = this.files[0])) {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
               if ( this.width != w  || this.height != y) {
                  alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
               };
            };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
        }
    });
});
```

My question: is there a way I can use the `result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayWidth"]`and `result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayHeight"]` along with "this.width" and "this.height" to make sure the the selected image dimensions are the same as the selected screen resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how this is done and updated my question code to reflect